# Polymer's handling of undefined (sub)properties

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, undefined, custom-element

Recently we had an issue in our Polymer application which we could fix by setting a value to `null` instead of `undefined`. So our tool works fine again.

But I would like to take this issue as a chance to have a look under Polymer's hood. Unfortunately, it's not easy to explain. So I have set up a [small example at JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4717p1sq/4/) and would like you to play with it according to the following steps and answer my big "Why?" question about it. Would be great!

### Intro

The example is about setting a path to `undefined` so I wired two custom elements `x-producer` and `x-consumer`. The buttons allow you to set the value of `x-producer` which is bound to a `h1` in `x-consumer`.

### Happy path:

1. Click 'Set Foo: A' button. *Producer property change is reflected in "foo.bar in consumer" heading.*
2. Click 'Set Bar: 1' button. *Sub-property of producer's property changes, this is also reflected in "foo.bar in consumer" heading.*
3. Click 'Set Bar: undefined' button. *Sub-property of producer's property is set to `undefined`, this is also reflected in "foo.bar in consumer" heading.*
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 as often you want to. *Every change of producer's sub-property is reflected in consumer's heading.*

### Un-happy path:

1. Click 'Set Foo: A' button. *Same as in happy path.*
2. Click 'Set Bar: 1' button. *Same as in happy path.*
3. Click 'Set Foo: B' button. *Producer's property (and thus sub-property) changes, which is reflected in "foo.bar in consumer" heading.*
4. Click 'Set Foo: A' button. *Producer's property (and thus sub-property) changes to the first property. In "foo.bar in consumer" heading you see the corresponding value again.*
5. Click 'Set Bar: undefined' button. *Sub-property of producer's property is set to `undefined`. This is also reflected in the `p` element of the producer, **but not in "foo.bar in consumer" heading**.*

### Make un-happy path happy again

Just set the sub-property to `null` instead of `undefined` in listener `_onButtonBarUndefined`.

### Some thoughts

In both cases the same code is executed which sets a sub-property to `undefined`. But in the first case, the property stays the same object, while the property is switched in the second case. I don't know if it matters to set a *sub*-property to `undefined`, but I think so.

Once again, it would be great if someone could explain me the inner mechanics of Polymer which lead to this behavior. THank you very much.